# What are the values of score for different actions

Tags: endless-legend

What is the score amount for each action?

I am asking this in context of the score victory, and the "best score in the first 25 turns" achievement. I used to think that expanding to a new region gave the most score but I think I am mistaken since expanding 8 times in 25 turns didn't give me the score lead.

Some actions that probably have a score value : research, making a unit, expanding. There is probably a file in the game programming that details all this but I was not able to find it.

Answer (score 2):

The scores for various actions are available in the install location. For the future I found this in the folder **....\Steam\steamapps\common\Endless Legend\Public\Statistics and Achievements\**, on Windows. The file is **GameScoreDefinitions.xml**. The overall score seems to be a weighted sum, which means you multiply the weight by the value. E.g: Knowing 3 technologies is worth 3*5.0 = 15 points towards overall score. Data in the file listed below.

```
<GameScoreDefinition Name="GlobalScore" Tags="Global,Ranked">
 <WeighedGameStatisticReference Name="SumOfAllUnitsLevels"     Weight="2.0"/>
 <WeighedGameStatisticReference Name="SumOfAllHeroesLevels"    Weight="5.0"/>
 <WeighedGameStatisticReference Name="NumberOfCities"          Weight="5.0"/>
 <WeighedGameStatisticReference Name="NumberOfDistricts"       Weight="2.0"/>
 <WeighedGameStatisticReference Name="NumberOfLevel1Districts" Weight="5.0"/>
 <WeighedGameStatisticReference Name="NumberOfLevel2Districts" Weight="10.0"/>
 <WeighedGameStatisticReference Name="TotalPopulation"         Weight="3.0"/>
 <WeighedGameStatisticReference Name="NumberOfImprovements"    Weight="1.0"/>
 <WeighedGameStatisticReference Name="NumberOfTechnologies"    Weight="5.0"/>
</GameScoreDefinition>
```